# Modify a value returned from Invoke-sqlcmd

Tags: powershell

I've searched for a number of hours now and am unable to figure out how to do this.

I query an MSSQL database that returns 2 columns, one of these values is empty/null but does represent something in the SQL database(I've tested disabling it).

How would I check through what is returned from my query for the empty value and modify this to something else?

```
$TestQuery = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Database $DB -Query $qcd -ServerInstance "SomeInstance\Instance1" -Verbose
```

Result:

```
Activity              Setting
--------              -------
All Operation         Enabled
Backup                Enabled
Restore               Enabled
Prune                 Enabled
Aux Copy              Enabled
Schedule              Enabled
Archive Check         Enabled
Tape Erase            Enabled
Offline content Index Enabled
Online Content Index  Enabled
                      Enabled
```

You can see the last item returned doesn't have a value but does reflect a setting in the application we use, I just want to modify that value to "Value1" for example.

Any help is greatly appreciated, I did try using hashtables but had no idea what I was doing despite several hours of googling.

Edit:
My Query:

```
SELECT JM.opName AS 'Activity',
    CASE action
    WHEN 1 THEN 'Disabled'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'Enabled'
    END AS 'Setting'
    FROM JMJobAction AS J
    LEFT JOIN JMJobOperationNames JM on JM.opType = J.opType
WHERE clientId = 1
    AND appType = 0
    AND J.opType != 8
    AND appId = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do the following in PowerShell:

```
$TestQuery = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Database $DB -Query $qcd -ServerInstance "SomeInstance\Instance1"
$TestQuery |
    Where { [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.Activity) } | Foreach-Object {
        $_.Activity = 'Value1' # Update all empty or nulls with Value1
    }
$TestQuery # Contains updated results
```

Note that this does not update the actual database. You will need a separate query that writes back to the database.

---

When a database table contains a `NULL`, it is interpreted as the `System.DBNull` data type in PowerShell. `[System.DBNull]::Value` is not the same as `$null`. So if you only wanted to query for `NULL` values, then your query could more appropriately be modified to the following:

```
$TestQuery | Where Activity -is [DBNUll]
```

Comment: I did read somewhere that a DB Null is not the same as $null. But thank you so much, this has resolved the issue I was having, I couldn't figure out how to do this within the SQL query but this is the next best thing.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand your question correctly.
I understand that you want to have a default_value when there is no data in a column.

That can be solved in your SQL Query with `case`. Here an example

[Edit] Based on your added query

```sql
SELECT 
    CASE 
      WHEN JM.opName is null OR JM.opName = '' THEN "DefaultActivity" 
      ELSE JM.opName
    END AS Activity,
    CASE action
       WHEN 1 THEN 'Disabled'
       WHEN 2 THEN 'Enabled'
    END AS 'Setting'
FROM JMJobAction AS J
    LEFT JOIN JMJobOperationNames JM on JM.opType = J.opType
WHERE clientId = 1
    AND appType = 0
    AND J.opType != 8
    AND appId = 1
```

Comment: So I'm not sure how to add this into my query, I've added my query into my first post

I just keep breaking the query

Comment: Hi @Mike, I have updated my answer. Unfortunately I cannot test it, I dont have such database :)  but give this a try and let me know if there are errors